# Prevent multiple users from registering with the same email

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

As I said in the title, I'm trying to prevent registering with the email that's already in the database. I tried it with the code below, but it's still registering new users even though the email is the same. What should I fix?

```
<?php

$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'];

    $chk = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =  :email");
    $chk->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $chk->execute();


    if ($chk->rowCount() > 0):
        $msg = 'That email is not available!';
    elseif ($chk->rowCount() == 0):
        if ($password != $cPassword)
            $msg = "Passwords don't match!";
        else {
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $con->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$hash')");
            $msg = "Registration successful!";
        }
    else:
        $msg = 'Registration not successful!';
    endif;

}
?>
```

Comment: Don't rely on the output of a SELECT query to avoid inserting duplicates. In a multi-user system, another process could insert into the database between the time when your SELECT runs and your subsequent INSERT runs, and then you'll get duplicates. Instead, create a UNIQUE constraint on the field in question and then verify that your INSERT succeeded.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Or use a transaction to prevent that.

Comment: You don't need `elseif` when the condition is the opposite of `if`, just use `else`.

Comment: Also note, your INSERT is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks because you didn't use a prepared statement with bound parameters there.

Comment: And we know you know how to use bound parameters, since you did it in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I changed 'email' in database to be unique, so now when I try to register I'm getting - Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email. --- So now I should just change my code so when this happens I get a message instead?

Comment: You need a `try/catch` to detect the error and report that the email is in use.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that makes sense, like I would do in any other language that has it.. Thank you, I shall not ask such obvious questions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the php docs:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of matching rows.

`rowCount` is mostly used in case of `DELETE` statements or `UPDATEs` but not in `SELECTs`.

For your case the easiest would be to change your query to directly return the number of users with the same email:

```
$chk = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email =  :email");
```

You can then get the value with:

```
$count = $chk->fetchColumn();
```

And then use $count in you if statement.